# Extension to redirect a Customer to a payment page

Tags: extensions

I have just studied Magento developer's guide for about 20 or so minutes. I am doing a simple research to check out how difficult or easy it would be to integrate a system to Magento.

**A quick question:**

I want to create an extension for Magento Check out page. When a customer opts to pay through say, debit card, the customer will be redirected to a payment gateway page which will take further details of the card, process the payment and redirect the customer back to the Magento page.

Is that possible? Or is it necessary to make an extension which will take the debit card details directly on Magento page?

Answer (score 1):

For you  1st require ,you can follow  [inchoo blog,](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)where they are describe in details.

On redirectAction as you ger customer last order from checkout seesion

So on `redirectionAction`  need to  call a  `phtml file` which hidden submit your form with last order data at `your payment gateway site`

Most ofpayment gateway site are require  a url in where they have sended data from you site.

Now from send data your can get  required date at your return url controller action